# Why does postgres query return 0?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This query returns the desired result:

```
Select * from media
```

This query returns 0:

```
select id from media where conc_title = 'origin of life'
```

conc_title has the type varchar and the entry is in the db.

these modifications don't work either:

```
SELECT id FROM media WHERE TRIM(conc_title) = 'origin of life'

SELECT id FROM media WHERE conc_title LIKE '%origin of life%'
```

Doesn't work for other conc_titles either. The result is the datatype without any rows.

Comment: When you says "returns 0", do you mean the value `0`, or zero rows? Have you made sure the capitalisation is correct? Have you tried other titles? *(The simple answer is that you've made a mistake, in you expectations or your query, not that postgresql has made a mistake.)*

Comment: Try `where lower(conc_title) like '%origin%'`? I suspect a case issue. If this doesn't return anything, can you share the results of `select * from media`?

Comment: You are a life saver. How do I mark your solution as the accepted answer? @sp00m

Comment: Glad I could help, I've added it as an answer that you should be able to accept.

Comment: Declare a case-insensitive collation for the column(s). Problem solved, forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect a case issue, try lowercasing the title before comparing it:

```
where lower(conc_title) like '%origin%'
```

Note that this won't use the index on `conc_title` if any, so to be used carefully depending on your dataset. Another approach could be to store the title lowercased already, perhaps in a separated column so that you keep the original case available. The `like` operator also may do a fulltable scan depending on how it's used, check with the dbms you're using.

Comment: Or simpler ,`where conc_title ilike '%origin%'`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest

```
SELECT id FROM media WHERE REPLACE(conc_title, ' ', '') = REPLACE('origin of life', ' ', '');
```

This approach helps if spaces are causing the mismatch. If this doesn't resolve the issue, verify the data for hidden characters or mismatches in the `conc_title` values.

Answer (score -2):

Postgres does never return NULL in case no result was found.
In case no result for a given condition was found 0 is returned.

You can use coalesce in case you want to have values OR really NULL. This would make it more transparent as a human reader.